# Plotting interaction graph solely based on slope

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw a publication ready graph (ideally with ggplot), based on the results of a structural equation model (semTools) with a latent interaction using the probe2WayMC function. The results of the corresponding wald-test look e.g. like this:

[image]

The package also contains a plotting-function yielding the following graph:

[image]

However, I want to be able to customize this graph, ideally via ggplot2, to use it for a publication. Does anybody have an idea on how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the documentation for `probe2WayMC` you can transorm the `plotProbe` functionality to ggplot fairly simple. This function should do the trick. It outputs the ggplot version of the graph and the data used to plot it (you can then do any ggplot manipulations on the graph to make your publication ready plot.

```
# Function to plot #####
make_ggplot_from_res <- function(model_res,xlim=c(0,1)){
  # make slope and intercept matrices dfs to enable merging

  slope_df = data.frame(model_res$SimpleSlope,check.names=F)
  if (is.null(model_res$SimpleIntcept)){
    # set intercepts to 0 if none provided per documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/semTools/versions/0.5-2/topics/probe2WayMC
    intcept_df = slope_df %>% dplyr::mutate(Intcept = 0)
} else{
  intcept_df = data.frame(model_res$SimpleIntcept,check.names=F)
}
  var_name = colnames(intcept_df)[1] # get the name of the independent variable
  
  # combine the slope and intercept data and make segment endpoints
  plot_df = intcept_df %>% dplyr::select(c(!!var_name,'Intcept')) %>%
    dplyr::left_join(slope_df %>% dplyr::select(c(!!var_name,'Slope')),
              by=var_name) %>%
    # make segment endpoints for geom_segment
    dplyr::mutate(x_start=xlim[1],x_end=xlim[2],
           y_start = Intcept + Slope*x_start,
           y_end = Intcept + Slope*x_end)
  
  # make graph
  g = ggplot(plot_df) +
    geom_segment(mapping=aes(x=x_start,y=y_start,
                             xend=x_end,yend=y_end,linetype=factor(!!sym(var_name),
                                                                   levels=intcept_df[[var_name]])),
                 data=plot_df,color='red') +
    labs(linetype=var_name,y='Dependent Variable',
         x='Independent Variable')
  # return graph and df used to plot
  return(list('graph'=g,'df'=plot_df))
}
```

Here's a plot using the `plotProbe` function and the function above using the sample model from the documentation

[image: plotProbe plot]
[image]

```
### Sample data
dput(res)
# list(SimpleIntcept = structure(c(-1, 0, 1, -0.295017001131069,
#                                  0.0999899491957403, 0.49499689952255, 0.0186534001703637, 0.0128351046903715,
#                                  0.0186533983268727, -15.8157225190391, 7.79034932771136, 26.5365533319171,
#                                  0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("f2", "Intcept",
#                                                                                       "SE", "Wald", "p"))),
#      SimpleSlope = structure(c(-1, 0, 1, 0.223827421273507,
#                                0.41762342244764, 0.611419423621773, 0.0169660243758487, 0.0136308937056807,
#                                0.0182349913093169, 13.1926853525053, 30.6380074164612, 33.5300090496548,
#                                0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("f2", "Slope",
#                                                                                     "SE", "Wald", "p"))))

### Call to function and draw plot
graph_and_df = make_ggplot_from_res(res,xlim=c(-1,1))
graph_and_df$graph
```

Comment: Wow, that looks really good. I just wonder if there is a way to retrieve the simpleIntcept-list required in your function. Looking at the probe2wayMC-function it just returns NULL as value for the simple intercepts.

Comment: I didn't know it shows up as NULL in some cases. I updated the function to check if there's a non-NULL list item named `SimpleIntcept` and if so, it will set the intercept to 0 for all lines. You might have to look out for the name of that list item. The documentation for version 0.5-3 of SemTools says that the list items are "SimpleSlope" and "SimpleIntercept", but the result I get has "SimpleIntcept". So you might have to change the list item name and potentially data.frame column names depending on your version.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Unfortunately, I still get the following error message:

 Error in select(., c(var_name, "Intcept")) : 
  unused argument (c(var_name, "Intcept")) 

Wouldn't there be a way to quickly calculate the SimpleIntcept-list? Btw, I think this is a typo in the function, I'm also getting it ("SimpleIntcept").

Comment: The change I previously made just uses the df made from the SimpleSlope matrix and adds a column named Intcept and sets it to 0 for all values. Can you use the dput function on your result of the `probe2WayMC` function and post the output in the question so I can see the data you have running through the plotting function? I thought the `SimpleIntcept` list entry was just NULL but I think it's something else

Comment: Using the dput-function yields the following results:

dput(int_a_i) list(SimpleIntcept = NULL, SimpleSlope = structure(c(4, 9, 16, -1.06573407957212, -2.37397113341665, -4.20550300879899, 0.221245648988749, 0.497372489045245, 0.884063342148471, -4.81697192438942, -4.77302461576377, -4.75701548554053, 1e-06, 2e-06, 2e-06), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list( NULL, c("AGE", "Slope", "SE", "Wald", "p"))))

Any hints on how to modify the function are much appreciated.

Comment: The function ran fine for me with your data. My assumption is that there's another `select` function in your namespace besides the dplyr package so I added explicit calls to the package using `dplyr::select` and likewise for the mutate and left_join functions (https://community.rstudio.com/t/select-function-in-dplyr-package/11737).